# Li display inline within a div that has max width

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="actions-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="#answer-form">
                            <img src="images/icons/answer.gif" class="answer-icon icon"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="" href="">
                            Action1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="">
                            <img src="images/icons/answer.gif" class="answer-icon icon"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="" href="">
                            Action2
                        </a>
                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hello, I have the previous code.
My div has a max size, and i want to display the li inline, but at the end of the line, i dont want the  containing the icon to be separated from its text within the same li.

In my css i have the following :

```
.actions-wrapper  ul { line-height: 25px;padding: 0; margin:0; list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none;display: block; }
.actions-wrapper ul li    { display:inline; margin-right: 12px;padding:3px 0;}
```

I have tried to put : white-space: nowrap; to the li, but it doesnt work in IE.

Here's a jsfiddle of my code : http://jsfiddle.net/wSTQy/1/
In this example the "Another action" is not on the same line of its icon.
If i add the white-space : nowrap; it wont work anymore in IE6

Comment: Please make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code. You can use [http://dummyimage.com/](http://dummyimage.com/) to replace the icons with.. dummy images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does adding the text-alignment to the `ul` achieve what you want?

```
.actions-wrapper  ul { 
  text-align: right;
}
```

### Updated after new information

changing the display of the `li` to `inline-block` instead of `inline` (needs a hack for IE7 and below) seems to work, even without the `white-space: nowrap;`

#### Updated fiddle (with hack included) : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/BPR2M/)

Comment: Ok it was hard to imagine before the fiddle, but I've now updated my answer with an updated fiddle

Comment: OK great the inline-block works. I tend to not use the inline block since it doesnt work in IE, but i didnt think of hack.

Comment: You're welcome, the IE7 workaround for inline-blocks doesn't have to be in a hack, if you've got an IE conditional CSS you can put the display inline rule in there (without the !ie7 bit), as long as it stays in a separate ruleset and comes after the main CSS ;)

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your markup, seems you want the icon and the text to make the same action.

Why not use css to add the icon next to the text, like so:

```
<li>
    <a href="#answer-form" id="icon-label">
        Action1
    </a>
</li>

With the CSS:
#icon-label {
    background: transparent url(path/to/image) no-repeat x y;
}
```

Comment: with some left padding to keep the text off the image

Comment: Good o'l padding-left. Thanks shanethehat

Comment: That worked too, but since my icon were famfamfam icons, it was easier for me to do the other method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing all the whitespace from between the anchors, and separating them with a `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to change `display:inline` to `float:left`. That way the icons and the text never get separated.